# tinymce how to insert video?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

Is there a plugin for tinymce to insert a video direct to the editor?

```
jwplayer(id).setup({
                    file: video.href,
                    image: video.img,
                    title: video.title,
                    width: '640',
                    height: '360',
                    primary: 'flash',
                    aspectratio: '16:9'
                });
```

or how to insert a `jwplayer` into the editor directly , does anyone has did this?

Comment: Which version of TinyMCE are you using? 3.x series or 4.x?

Comment: @ChankeyPathak, 4x tinymce...I want to insert the jwplayer programmatically to the editor, or any other plugin if its possible, for example I click a button(whereas have a link to the video) and then it appears in the editor....as, but the problem is that jwplayer is not inserting as html, it executes as javascript, i can't find examples for this...

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839345/jwplayer-and-tinymce

Comment: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/media/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is:

You can use the `media` plugin.

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "media"
});
```

This plugin adds the ability to add HTML5 video and audio elements to TinyMCE.

Also check out [TinyMce-JwPlayer-plugin](https://github.com/ssm2017/TinyMce-JwPlayer-plugin)

Comment: I'mean how to use it for example not as an User intefrace, but programmatically insert the code into the editor to make the video appear?, can't find examples...

Comment: is there a version for tinymce 4.x?

Comment: did u find a solution @user3518675?

Comment: How can you upload .mp4 files?